# Splitting long file path in Stata

Tags: stata

Assume that I have a long file path (80+ characters) from my current working folder:

```
use .\random_folders_name\project1\secret_data\survey_data\big_constructed_file.dta
```

I am looking for a way to split it into two lines to comply with a 80-character-line standard.

I've tried

```
    use .\random_folders_name\project1\secret_data\survey_data///
         \big_constructed_file.dta
```

and

```
    use ".\random_folders_name\project1\secret_data\survey_data"///
         + "\big_constructed_file.dta"
```

without success.

I would prefer to not change the working directory as that would make necessary to change it back.

Comment: I am setting "working directory" with `cd` only once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` can be used for string concatenation but only within an expression to be evaluated.

This works

```
clear 
set obs 1 
gen whatever = "a" + "b"
```

and this works

```
local whatever = "a"  + "b" 
di "`whatever'"
```

Putting one or more parts of a string in a local macro is one way to do what you want and what I would recommend if writing within 80 characters on a line.

```
local dir ".\random_folders_name\project1\secret_data\survey_data\"
use "`dir'big_constructed_file.dta"
```

You could do this:

```
local name = ".\random_folders_name\project1\secret_data\survey_data" + /// 
"\big_constructed_file.dta"
use "`name'"
```

That's the closest I could get to taking your approach and making it work.

On backslashes, watch out: http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0042